# Unifying Receiver hooks up 100% for BIOS setup but only 20% for Win7 login

Tags: windows-7, bios, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have a Logitech keyboard (K750) and mouse (M950) on a single unifying receiver. During boot up I can hit Del to go into my Gigabyte motherboard setup, or I can let it go to reach the login screen for Win7.

I have a 100% success rate of being able to hit the Del key to go into setup, where I can use the mouse and keyboard perfectly, every time.

But I only have about a 20% success rate of the mouse and keyboard registering with the unified receiver at the Win7 login screen. If it doesn't register, all I can do is reboot and hope next time it will pick it up. Usually after about 5 times it picks it up - sometimes it can be first or second go, sometimes it can be the 8th attempt. I've tried various USB ports and the other unifying receiver I have. Once registered they work perfectly - it just seems to have difficulty getting there.

Why would it be 100% for the BIOS entry, but only 20% for the Win7 login screen?

Is there something in the BIOS I need to set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For troubleshooting i would just boot straight to desktop without log-in screen by temporarily disabling user password... If you still find non functioning KB and mouse in Windows desktop than its sure USB driver issue. 
You can try uninstalling all usb ports from device manager including non-present ones by following...
At the command prompt, type the following lines, pressing ENTER after each line

set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

cd\%SystemRoot%\System32

start devmgmt.msc

select show hidden devices on the Device Manager View menu

click on each usb device and uninstall and reboot afterwards windows will install usb driver upon reboot

Comment: Thanks dccet - sorry, offline for a few days - disabling password worked 100% but I need login screen for passwords unfortunately. Oddly the problem has rectified itself since trying another USB port on the usb hub (actually a monitor) - not sure why but I get keyboard registering 100% of the time and mouse about 50% of the time (as soon as I hit Enter to Login mouse connects 100%). Not sure  why the difference - the past USB slot seems fine once logged in. Cheers.